# Is there a way to reduce the top margin for a compact look between a heading and subheading in latex?

Tags: latex

I am creating a resume template and I want to provide a Centered Heading which is my name and centered subheading  which is my personal details like email and phone number.I am trying to reduce the space between the heading and subheading to gain more space on the entire page.
Code so far:

```
\begin{center}
    \huge \scshape ABC

\end{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}  
 \hfill    \textit +00000000---abc@test.com---linkedin.com/in/testuser\\
    \end{minipage}
        \bspace
```

Current Output:https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqSyF.jpg
Expected Output:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqwyk.jpg

Comment: The `center` environment adds additional vertical space. Try `{\centering text}` instead. If this does not help, please make a minimal but compilable example

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, don't input email adresses as normal text, have a look at the url or hyperref packages instead